# Monitors not Found After Nvidia Driver Update (situation details included)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

**Background**

I plugged an Nvidia GTX 650 Ti into a desktop computer running Kubuntu 13.04. I started out following [this guide on dedoimedo.com](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html), moving on to the [general Nvidia driver omnianswer here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers). The advice there (and that accessible through the relevant links) has been tried.

**Current situation**

The GPU is found. `lspci | grep -i vga` returns `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti] (rev a1)`.

The Edgers PPA is active, using the `nvidia-325` driver package. Jockey says it has been enabled, but not in use. 319, 313, 310 and 304 (the last one being set up by nvidia-current, apparently) do not improve the situation. [Jockey-text -l output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5951093/)

The `xorg.conf` file is generated by `nvidia-xconfig`, run after enabling the driver via Jockey. [My xorg.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5951077/) (Oddity: `nvidia-xconfig` does not run from anywhere. I have to go into the nvidia-325 directory and run it from there.)

Normal startup results in the Kubuntu logo flashing for a second or two. But instead of the login screen appearing, the monitor goes blank.

Going into recovery mode and running `startx` gives a `no screens found` error. [The error log in Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5951087/)

By deleting `xorg.conf`, I can boot normally into a barely-functioning KDE. Default resolution very low, window title bars not visible, desktop effects off, and so on.

**The Question**

Where do I go from here to get a functional, accelerated desktop environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was hardware related.

Took the card back to the shop, they quickly determined that its memory was damaged. Got a new one (same model), plugged it in, and it immediately worked with the same drivers and xorg configuration.

I have now learned to check the screen for artifacts, and to remember that sometimes the error really isn't yours.